# Angular Radio Button Binding using true false value

Tags: angular, data-binding

I noticed I must use [value]=true as opposed to value = true in order for my radio button to get the initial value from the component class. How is this working - does putting brackets around value somehow tell Angular to use the initial value from [(ngModel)]?

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id ="yesChoice" [(ngModel)] ="serverDeluxe" [value]=true  >
<label for="yesChoice">Yes</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id ="noChoice"  [(ngModel)] ="serverDeluxe" [value]=false >
<label for="noChoice">No</label>
```

TS:

```
export class ServerComponent implements OnInit{
  serverId = 10;
  serverStatus = 'offline';
  serverDeluxe = true;

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  getServerStatus(): string{
    return this.serverStatus;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#remember-the-brackets):

> The brackets, `[]`, tell Angular to evaluate the template expression. If
> you omit the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and
> initializes the target property with that string:
>
> ```
> <app-item-detail childItem="parentItem"></app-item-detail>
> ```
>
> Omitting the brackets will render the string `"parentItem"`,
> not the value of `parentItem`.

In your case, the brackets allow to set the radio input to a boolean value:

```
[value]="true" <---- Sets the value to the boolean true
value="true"   <---- Sets the value to the string "true"
```

The initial value of `serverDeluxe` is bound to the control with `[ngModel]` (which is a part of `[(ngModel)]`). Since `serverDeluxe` is a boolean property, it will never match the string `"true"` or `"false"`.

Comment: thanks so I understand the brackets part now, however how does serverDeluxe bind it's value to [value] on load? For example if it is false, the radio button's will start with false. How is it doing that?

Comment: The initial value of `serverDeluxe` is bound to the control with `[ngModel]` (which is also a part of `[(ngModel)]`). I added that part to the answer.

Comment: So it is matching to the [value] and then setting checked to true if the value matches?

Comment: That is my understanding, and the behavior that we observe. You could can take a look at the code of [ngModel](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts), [RadioControlValueAccessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/radio_control_value_accessor.ts) and their base classes if you want to know the exact inner workings of the `ngModel` binding for radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working for you because of `[value]` property.
It treats the value as a dynamic value(as template expression) hence html is able to bind the radio option.

If we will provide `value=true` instead of `[value]=true` then we will have to provide `name` property.

For `value=true` it will take as `value="true"` and for `[value]=true` as `value=true`

Comment: thanks but the radio buttons above work fine without the name option, my question is how is my example working without the name option?

Comment: Edited my response to the question